# Java - Sorting results

Tags: java, sorting

I have an equation : `A = b^2 + 4*c^2`

I change a value of 'b' and 'c' like this: `b=1,2,3,4,5,...`   and   `c=1,2,3,4,5,...`
and I put them in equation.

I want to create a table of results (as an output), something like this:

```
      b  c  A
      1  1  5
      1  2  17
      2  1  8
      2  2  20
      4  1  20
      ........
```

However, I want to have table sorted from smallest value of A towards the biggest.
Note that it can occur that different pairs of b and c give the same A.
I want to create table like that for 10 different values of A.

My problem is that I don't know how to 'link' value A with proper value of b and c, when I try to sort the table

Comment: create a class that holds the three variables

Answer (score 5):

You may create a class that represent three values and then sort.

```
class Tuple implement Comparable<Tuple>{

     int a, b, c;
     //....
     int compareTo(Tuple tuple) {
         return Integer.compare(a, tuple.a);
     }

}

Tuple[] tuples;
// ...
Arrays.sort(tuples);
```

Answer (score 1):

One Simple method:

Make a 3 column array, and when you sort by the A column, take the rest of the row with you.

There are many possibilities.